# Uploading files to flask

Tags: python, flask, upload, python-requests, chunks

So I have been searching for a clear and complete answer to this with no luck so far. Hoping someone here can help. 
I have a web app that I need to be able to have a user upload a file. The user puts in an email address to associate with the file and submits both to the server for processing. I need it to be able to handle large files so chunking/streaming. 
I was able to get a basic dropzone to work but not with being able to also send the email address at the same time. 
Is there a way to upload files in chunks along with additional data?

Comment: where do you want the email to be stored?

Comment: The email will be getting pushed into a database along with a blob of the file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are asking for a place to upload files and match them with an email. This can be done with a simple HTML form. All you need is an upload button and email address box, but you can include whatever else you want as well. Please check out my code at [my code](https://github.com/Rahul-Datta/Uploading-files-to-flask). I think it would be really helpful.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks but this app needs to be able to serve large files and the way you provided loads the entire file into memory. In my case that would tank the server. It needs to be able to chunk the file.